# Sistering a stud around a pipe

Tags: framing

There is a vent pipe in the near exact location that a shower door will be going. I am unable to use the shower curb as an attachment point because it will be made of Kerdi material, so I am left with attaching the door frame to the studs. The door and frame cannot attach to just the wall finish because I will be using Kerdi board and tile. The vent pipe will need to be rerouted to the side in order to make room for the new stud, but I am not sure how to go about making sure the new stud will be structurally sound enough to support a door and frame.

The location of the door is not able to move. It cannot go any further to the right (with respect to the first photo) because then the shower will be smaller than what code allows. It cannot go any further to the left because there is a perpendicular wall directly across from the vent pipe. There is about 3/4" of space behind the existing vent pipe and around 1.5" to the left.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "a shower door"? We'd have to know that to answer your question. Please revise your post to add detail about your overall plans, including wall finish. It's possible you don't even need to move the pipe.

Comment: I updated the post with more detail. I don't think that there is any way around moving the vent pipe unless I use a prefab shower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the shower door is the frame for holding a swinging glass/plexiglass door, I'd agree with you that a piece of 2x6 attached like that will not be sufficient to hold the door up.

It's hard to know how big the pipe is in relation to the studs. If it's small enough, you can run several 2x4s on edge (with the 4" direction running vertically) between the two existing studs. Once those are in place, put your new stud in on the flat (with the 4" direction facing the room, instead of the 2" direction) and attach it to your horizontal bracing. Then you'll be able to attach your shower door to this new stud on the flat.

Here's a wonderful bit of MS Paint to show what I mean from a top-down view:

[image]

- The black rectangles are the existing studs and the black circle is your rerouted pipe.
- The green rectangle represents the several pieces of horizontal blocking
- The red rectangle represents the new stud on the flat
- The blue line is a piece of 1/2" plywood/OSB/etc between the stud & blocking to make up the full thickness of a stud.

The added advantage is that you'll have a 3.5" wide target to get the stud & door lined up instead of only a 1.5" wide target. It gives you a little extra leeway in getting it placed.

---

Based on the update (in a comment) that there's only about 3/4" clearance between the pipe and the back wall, here's an updated drawing:

[image]

- Black and red are as above
- Green is a 1x or 3/4" plywood/OSB
- Blue is 2x2 lumber
- Purple shows the direction of fasteners

Use the blue 2x2 (or something that will fit in the available space) as a "fillet" in the corner. If at all possible screw/nail through the backing piece into the fillet (If you can't, make sure of your fastener lengths so you don't blow through the back of the green piece and through the drywall/whatever is behind this stud bay), then fasten through the stud into the fillet. Finally, put the red "hinge hanger" on fastening through it into the fillet and through the stud into it.

Obviously, you'll use more than one nail/screw in each of these locations - I'm only showing a single one for simplicity and as an example.

If you can't get a 2x2 on each corner, then use a smaller piece. It's just got to be big enough to support the fasteners going into it. Remember, though that if it's too small, a nail or screw will split it. You can pre drill (even in soft pine) for a screw to help prevent splitting.

All this extra material *should* give enough stability to the red 2x4 so it can support the weight & movement of the shower door. Again, though, if you can mount the hinge side of the door on the other side, it should be much easier (from what I can see of the most recent picture) to get a strong, stable mount there. If this is the latch side of the door, it won't take nearly as much stress and you will definitely be safe getting away with some "make shift" construction like this.

Not sure what happened to your drawing showing how you planned to shift this pipe, but it seems important.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added more detail to the post. With the layout of the shower, the center of where the curb will go is basically on the right edge of the vent pipe. If I try to attach the door frame to the left of the vent pipe then the shower will be poking out from the perpendicular wall by a few inches.

Comment: Presuming you want to put the hinge side where the pipe is, I don't see how this added info makes any difference. If you're willing to adapt, simply hinge the door on the other side where there is no pipe. It will take far less strength to hold the latch side of the door than it would the hinge side.

Comment: My mistake -- I read your comment incorrectly. I was thinking you meant to keep the vent pipe in place with the added stud to the left. I think this is my best bet, thank you! There is only about 3/4" of space available behind the pipe in the stud bay. Would something of that thickness be enough to use as the horizontal blocking?

Comment: I would think that 3/4" plywood or 1" (nominal) solid lumber would be sufficient to attach the new "red" stud to. However, you'll have to be creative in how you attach that thin material to the studs - you won't be able to nail/screw into the end of it very well. You always want to attach through the face of thinner material for something like this, so you'd need some extra solid lumber to make attachments with.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand. I believe you're saying I shouldn't attach the 1" blocking the same way I would with a 2x4 because its too thin, but I'm not sure what the correct way to attach it would be.

Comment: The toilet will be in the way of the door opening if I put the latch side there, unfortunately. I will try and choose a lightweight door and frame. Not sure what happened to my diagram -- it should be fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yet another random down vote without explanation. How petty.

Comment: @FreeMan, your answer, while inferior to mine, is very useful. I'll nullify.

Comment: Thanks, @popham. I'm not looking for pity votes. I'd just like the down voter to explain himself, especially since I have an idea of who it is and I think it's a petty tit-for-tat. If you have suggestions for improvement of my answer, I'm all ears.  TBH, your piece of plywood idea sounds pretty darn good, though not everyone can easily do pocket holes...

Answer (score 1):

Pocket screw 3/4" plywood across the whole wall cavity on the near side of the ABS. This 3/4" plywood, if spanned from near-floor to near-ceiling, is stiffer than a new wall stud would be. If it's a little tight against the ABS, then you'll have to stay away from the top and bottom a bit so that the pipe can flex into position behind the plywood. Once the plywood is in, you can optionally use a heat gun to relax the stresses that were introduced into the ABS.

To compare stiffness of the plywood to the baseline of a strongly oriented 2x4, consider the deflection due to 1# acting at mid-height of a 7'-0" tall 2x4. Applying the 1# load, the baseline deflection computes as

1#(84in)^3/[48(1000000psi)1/12(1.5in)(3.5in)^3] = 0.0023"

Now consider the "double tee" composite section with 3/4" OSB pocket screwed to the wall studs on either side of the pipe. For this composite section I get an effective moment of inertia of `19in^4`†, where I've derived an "effective `E`" of 650000psi for 48/24 OSB from Table M9.2-2 on page 53 from the [AWC Manual for Engineered Wood Construction](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/AWC-2018-Manual-1810.pdf).

The deflection of this double tee under 1# at midspan computes as

1#(84in)^3/[48(1000000psi)(19in^4)] = 0.00065"

The plywood spanning from stud-to-stud also deflects locally, so the composite's deflection still needs that component. Assuming that the deflection of a 6" tall band from stud to stud estimates the local deflection, Table M9.2-1 from page 52 of the [AWC Manual for Engineered Wood Construction](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/AWC-2018-Manual-1810.pdf) provides an `EI` for the weak direction bending of the 48/24 OSB, `(91500#-in^2/ft)(6in)(1ft)/(12in) = 45800#-in^2`. The deflection under a midspan load of 1# follows as

1#(14.5in)^3/[48(45800#-in^2)] = 0.0014"

Summing both deflection contributions, I get `0.00065" + 0.0014" = 0.0021"`, where that 0.0021" is less than the 0.0023" baseline deflection of a single 2x4 oriented strongly.

Sufficiently many pocket screws would need to be installed to develop the composite section's strength. I would develop the strength with the screws alone and then also apply Titebond III wood glue in the joints.

*† Effective Moment of Inertia*:

The 19 in^4 effective moment of inertia used above comes from the following methodology. The OSB has an effective modulus of elasticity of 650000psi, so the 1000000psi modulus of the studs results in a 0.65 ratio of moduli. The effective area is `2(1.5")(3.5") + 0.65(14.5")(0.75") = 18in^2`. The composite section's neutral axis is at

[2(1.5")(3.5")(3.5"/2) + 0.65(14.5")(0.75")(3.5"-0.75"/2)]/18in^2 = 2.3"

The effective moment of inertia contribution from the wall framing follows as

1/12(2)(1.5")(3.5")^3 + (1.5")(3.5")(2.30" - 1.75")^2 = 14 in^4

The effective moment of inertia contribution from the plywood follows as

0.65[1/12(14.5")(0.75")^3 + (14.5")(0.75")(3.5" - 0.375" - 2.30")^2] = 5.1 in^4

The sum of these contributions provides the composite section's effective moment of inertia, `14 in^4 + 5.1 in^4 = 19 in^4`.